# Trouble parsing autocomplete response

Tags: parsing, autocomplete, prediction

Predictions for addresses in the U.S. seem consistent.  However when I get predictions for a U.K. address, I get inconsistent results.  For example here are some results I receive:

  * Pinewood Green, Iver, Buckinghamshire SL0 0QH, United Kingdom

  * Berkshire, William Street, Windsor SL4 1AA, United Kingdom

The first one is Address, City, **County**, Postal code, Country
The second is **County**, Address, City, Postal code, Country
The county's position changes.  I can find nothing in the response that would help me know from the response which field is what.
Additionally, with a response such as this

  * 20 High Street, East Hoathly, East Sussex BN8 6EB, United Kingdom

how do I tell where the county stops and the postal code starts?  Terms/Offsets?

Comment: Ok, I resolved the last question by using terms|value.  So I know where to 'separate' the county and the postal code.

Comment: Alright, I had to use a sledge hammer.  Using terms|value, I rebuilt the result so there was a comma between each field, including before the postal code.  I then checked the first field against a static county list if the country was 'United Kingdom'.  If that first field was a county, I reordered the first three fields.  Works so far...